# C++11 move semantics vs. pointers - a performance measurement

Tags: performance, c++11, move-semantics

for my use case I have to insert and remove data packets from a list very fast.

In my opinion there are two common ways to solve this:

- inserting/removing pointers to these packets
- inserting/removing copies by using move semantics

Anyhow I thought the solution with pointers should be the most efficient even with the disadvantage of your own garbage collection.

I implemented 3 test cases for a better comparison:

- using copies
- using move semantics
- using pointers

To measure the time elapsed for each test case I have also implemented a timer class:

```
class HighPerformanceTimer {

public:
    enum TimerResolution {
        SECONDS      = 1,
        MILLISECONDS = SECONDS * 1000,
        MICROSECONDS = MILLISECONDS * 1000,
        NANOSECONDS  = MICROSECONDS * 1000
    };


    explicit HighPerformanceTimer(const TimerResolution resolution = NANOSECONDS)
        : m_resolution(resolution)
        , m_frequency(0.0)
        , m_startTime({0})
        , m_stopTime({0}) {}
    ~HighPerformanceTimer(void) {}


    bool Init(void) {
        LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
        if(0 == ::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency)) {
            return false;
        }

        /* Check for zero divisor. */
        if(0 == frequency.QuadPart) {
            return false;
        }

        /* Change frequency to double for internal timer resolution. */
        switch(m_resolution) {
            case NANOSECONDS:
                m_frequency = frequency.QuadPart / (NANOSECONDS * 1.0);
                break;

            case MICROSECONDS:
                m_frequency = frequency.QuadPart / (MICROSECONDS * 1.0);
                break;

            case MILLISECONDS:
                m_frequency = frequency.QuadPart / (MILLISECONDS * 1.0);
                break;

            default:
                /**
                 * SECONDS
                 * m_frequency has a resolution in seconds by default
                 */
                m_frequency = frequency.QuadPart * 1.0;
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    void Start(void) {
        ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_startTime);
    }

    void Stop(double& intervall) {
        ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_stopTime);
        intervall = ((m_stopTime.QuadPart - m_startTime.QuadPart) / m_frequency);
    }

private:
    const TimerResolution     m_resolution;
    double                    m_frequency;
    LARGE_INTEGER             m_startTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER             m_stopTime;
    CRITICAL_SECTION          m_timerLock;

};
```

And here is my main class:

```
class Packet {

public:
    Packet(const uint8* data, uint16 length) {
        if(0 != length) {
            if(nullptr == data) {
                m_data = std::vector<uint8>(length, 0x00);
            } else {
                m_data.assign(data, data + length);
            }
        }
    }

    Packet(const Packet& rhs) : m_data(rhs.m_data) {}

    Packet& operator=(const Packet& rhs) {
        m_data = rhs.m_data;
        return *this;
    }

    Packet(const Packet&& rhs) : m_data(rhs.m_data) {}

    Packet& operator=(const Packet&& rhs) {
        m_data = rhs.m_data;
        return *this;
    }

    std::vector<uint8> m_data;

};

void Measurement_1(void);
void Measurement_2(void);
void Measurement_3(void);

constexpr uint16 payloadLength = 15000;
uint8 payload[payloadLength];

/* Initialize high performance timer. */
HighPerformanceTimer hpt(HighPerformanceTimer::MICROSECONDS);

int main(void) {
    hpt.Init();

    /* Fill packet data. */
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < payloadLength; ++j) {
        payload[j] = 0xFF;
    }


    Measurement_1();
    Measurement_2();
    Measurement_3();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void Measurement_1(void) {
    /* Measurement with copies. */

    double result[25];

    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < 25; ++k) {
        /* Start measurement. */
        double timeElapsed = 0.0;
        std::list<Packet> mylist;
        hpt.Start();
        /* Begin insertion. */
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
            Packet f(payload, payloadLength);
            mylist.push_back(f);
        }
        /* End insertion. */

        /* Begin removal. */
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
            Packet f = mylist.front();
            mylist.pop_front();
        }
        /* End removal. */
        hpt.Stop(timeElapsed);
        result[k] = timeElapsed;
        /* Stop measurement. */
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
        std::cout << "with copies: " << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed << result[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

void Measurement_2(void) {
    /* Measurement with move semantics. */

    double result[25];

    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < 25; ++k) {
        /* Start measurement. */
        double timeElapsed = 0.0;
        std::list<Packet> mylist;
        hpt.Start();
        /* Begin insertion. */
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
            Packet f(payload, payloadLength);
            mylist.push_back(std::move(f));
        }
        /* End insertion. */

        /* Begin removal. */
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
            Packet f = std::move(mylist.front());
            mylist.pop_front();
        }
        /* End removal. */
        hpt.Stop(timeElapsed);
        result[k] = timeElapsed;
        /* Stop measurement. */
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
        std::cout << "with moves: " << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed << result[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

void Measurement_3(void) {
    /* Measurement with pointers. */

    double result[25];

    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < 25; ++k) {
        /* Start measurement. */
        double timeElapsed = 0.0;
        std::list<Packet*> mylist;
        hpt.Start();
        /* Begin insertion. */
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
            mylist.push_back(new Packet(payload, payloadLength));
        }
        /* End insertion. */

        /* Begin removal. */
        Packet* f = nullptr;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
            f = mylist.front();
            if(nullptr != f) {
                mylist.pop_front();
                delete f;
            }
        }
        /* End removal. */
        hpt.Stop(timeElapsed);
        result[k] = timeElapsed;
        /* Stop measurement. */
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
        std::cout << "with pointers: " << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed << result[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

At the moment I have the problem that I receive nearly the same measurement result for the pointer version as well as for the move semantics and even the copy version.

Did I do a mistake anywhere?

Greets!

Comment: You'll get more reliable and accurate results if you run each test many more times than 25 (think several hundred thousand) and pick the fastest timing (or top 10%, say). This will reduce jitter between runs, reduce the impact of the OS scheduler swapping out your process in the middle of a test, and prime the CPU cache.

Comment: A small addition to @Cameron words: each of `Measurement_X` method call should take at least a few seconds (and preferably a few tens of seconds).

Comment: `Packet(const Packet&& rhs) : m_data(rhs.m_data) {}`... this *cannot* invoke move semantics. Try a `Packet(Packet&& rhs) noexcept`.

Comment: Your code is incorrect. && operators should not have const parameters, as mentioned by @DyP. They should copy pointers and zero them in another instance. First write correct code and be sure that && operators are called. Then measure performance.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to `std::move` the parameter: `Packet(Packet&& rhs) noexcept : m_data( std::move(rhs.m_data) ) {}`.

Comment: That's it. I simply didn't find the mistake on my own...

Answer (score 4):

The move constructor actually copies the other vector. It calls vector's copy constructor.

Here's a fix:

```
Packet(Packet&& rhs) : m_data(std::move(rhs.m_data)) {}
```

As far as timings, on my PC pointers was fastest.

- Pointers: **5500** on avg
- Move before fix: **8100** on avg
- Move after fix: **5500** on avg
- Copies: **8700** on avg

Results were quite consistent (in microseconds).

**Edit:**
After the fix, the move operator when ran enough time showed similar performance to the pointers time. Increasing the test time showed similar ratios.

**Results in debug mode:**

- Pointers: **16500** on avg
- Move after fix: **19000** on avg
- Copies: **30000** on avg

In debug builds, pointers is faster, probably due to implementation (how many inline functions are called).

Comment: Don't forget `noexcept`.

Comment: Could you try an `emplace_back` instead of a `push_back`?

Comment: `emplace_back` and `noexcept` did not change anything (performance)

Comment: Just wanted to write a comment wondering where the speed of pointers then comes from ;) Nice work.

Comment: Great! These results match my expectations of the performance of pointers.
Maybe I'll also try new measurements later on again.
Thank you so far!

Comment: In my understanding move constructors basically copy pointers behind the scenes between the old and new object. Custom move ctors do exactly that don't they? So, the performance should be very close. Not equal though since a single object will invoke several move operations for its members.